# static values works, how to make input values work?

Tags: javascript, html

this is working [code](http://pastebin.com/nqfrYApr) for computing a SUM from time values set in HTML.
My question is, how to make them work if I want to get time values from input. Changing all

```
<td class="duration_time">11:15</td>
```

into

```
<td><input type="text" class="duration_time" value="00:00"></td>
```

Comment: you answered your own question, change all <td> into input and wrap them in a form tag with an onsubmit calling foo()

Comment: maybe time.textContent.split(":") -> time.value.split(":")

Comment: Just use value instead of textcontent

Comment: As the boys said above, use `value` in your `foo` function instead of `textContent`.